# Qt creator not populating issues tab

Tags: qt-creator

The issues tab is never populated,
the 'compile output' tab is working fine, I can see all warnings and errors.

I have tried cmake and qmake projects,
compiling with gcc and clang.

Full working projects and just "main" empty projects.

I'm using Qt Creator 4.0.2

Comment: Same is happening to me with Qt Creator 4.0.2.

Comment: It's only happening for me on CMake projects, not on .pro projects.  Are you seeing the same behavior?

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to debug this. Does anyone know if there's a way to see internal failures or why certain lines in the compiler output aren't captured? There's gotta be some internal regex that's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, Qt Creator 4.0.x. I solved it by using the latest cmake version (currently 3.6.1).

You don't need to install latest cmake in the system, if you don't want to / don't have permissions. It also worked by downloading latest cmake binary tar, extracting it somewhere, and referencing it in qtcreator (Tools - Options - Build&Run - CMake - Add...) and setting it as default in the used kit (Tools - Options - Build&Run - Kits - CMake-Tool).